# Get value using data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need get a value using jquery "data()". but I need to do it by doing something like this. So please give me an idea . Thank you in advance.

```
//html

<div id="myid" data-cityid="Colombo" ></div>

var name = "cityid";

$("#myid").data(""+name+""); // this way not working :(
```

Comment: I can't believe everyone is answering `data(name)`. That can't be the right answer, because concatenating empty strings doesn't have any effect.

Comment: it should be just fine

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Fvymr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to get attribute, use `attr()` for it with complete name of attribute:

```
var name = "data-cityid";    
alert($("#myid").attr(name));
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nxq22/)

Comment: This is the same as Felix's answer, see my comments there.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

To get:

```
$("#myid").attr('data-cityid');
```

To set:

```
$("#myid").attr('data-cityid', name);
```

Comment: If `.data` doesn't work, why do you think `.attr` would work any better?

Comment: @Barmar are you sure `data` and `attr` has the same effect in this case?

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure. The documentation says: _Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-* attribute._

Comment: @Flex in this case .attr will be fine. because I dont want to update the data object. I just need to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try with attr.

```
$("#myid").attr("data-"+name);
```

Comment: See my comments to Felix's answer.